# NodeJS How to loop through query

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I am new to Node, I know exactly how to do what I want in PHP, I'm in node though. So no idea.

I have the following.

```
switch(args[0]) {
    case 'games':
        var games = con.query("SELECT name FROM games");
        message.channel.send('Available Games:');
}
```

My connection is already set-up and working. I just wanna know how to foreach through the data now to list what I want.

For instance, since I queried name in games, I want to the message back to show all the game names.

Can I foreach here? Not sure at all.

in php I would just

```
foreach($games as $games) {//stuff here}
```

That is not working though.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @T.Dirks Well it's not a duplicate. So....

Comment: @KevinM1990112qwq The main core of your question here is that you want to loop over an array of things (in this case names from a game database). The question I linked has answers which explain exactly that, how to loop over an array. It doesn't matter whether the data comes from an database or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all assumes games is an array, however you could do a few things:

If you just wanted to write the list of games into the output:

```
var games = con.query("SELECT name FROM games");
message.channel.send('Available Games:' + games.join(', '));
```

This would be equivilent to the following PHP code:

```
$games = ['halo', 'call of duty', 'destiny 2'];
$message->channel->send('Available Games:' . implode(', ', $games));
```

If you wanted to loop through them:

```
var games = con.query("SELECT name FROM games");
for (var i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
    var game = games[i];
}
```

This would be equivilent to the following PHP code:

```
$games = ['halo', 'call of duty', 'destiny 2'];
foreach ($games as $game) {
    // $game is in scope here
}
```

There are other array methods you can use such [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). But the scope is treated a little differently, and there can be a few gotchas. A lot of JavaScript devs will hate if you don't use the hip loops as opposed to good old fashioned for loops, [but the performance with them is negligibly worse when dealing with small to medium size datasets and relatively the same on larger datasets](https://github.com/dg92/Performance-Analysis-JS).

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options here but I'll mention the best ones,

you can use map (if you want to return something)

`games.map(game=>{/*STUFF*/})`

you can use forEach (if you don't want to return anything)

`games.forEach(game=>{/*STUFF*/})`

or "for of"

`for (const game of game){/*STUFF */}`